# How to get changed value of a select in Angular - Without updating a global model?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-model

I have several widgets which are generated from JSON data and an `ng-repeat`. Inside this widget is a select dropdown.

I'm able to call a function in my `Controller` with `ng-change`, however using `ng-model` on that select, *changes the chosen value for all selects dropdowns in all the widgets*.

**How would I prevent this?**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in widget.items" class="well col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <select ng-model="widget.chosenValue"
            ng-change="widget.updateTag(item.item_id, widget.chosenValue)">

        <option value="companies"
                ng-selected="{{item.tag == 'companies'}}"
                changed="companies">companies</option>

        <option value="news"
                ng-selected="{{item.tag == 'news'}}"
                changed="news">news</option>

        <option value="people"
                ng-selected="{{item.tag == 'people'}}"
                changed="people">people</option>

        <option value="products"
                ng-selected="{{item.tag == 'products'}}"
                changed="products">products</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

The model on the select: `ng-model="widget.chosenValue"`

^ So choosing an option in the select will send the correct value into my `widget.updateTag` function, however it also changes the value in every other widget.

Is there a way to isolate the model scope to each widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know what they selected you should replace

```
ng-model="widget.chosenValue"
ng-change="widget.updateTag(item.item_id, widget.chosenValue)
```

with

```
ng-model="item.chosenValue"
ng-change="widget.updateTag(item)
```

This applies the chosenValue to each item in the list, so it would look like

```
<div ng-repeat="item in widget.items" class="well col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <select ng-model="item.chosenValue"
            ng-change="widget.updateTag(item)">
```

Then in your updateTag function you can access

- item.item_id
- item.tag
- item.chosenValue

Comment: Yes, I am able to get the correct value, the problem is that every other widget that is in the `ng-repeat` also is showing the changed value. How would you prevent that?

Comment: If you look, I am using ng-model="item.chosenValue" instead of ng-model="widget.chosenValue" so it will only store the chosenValue for that item

Comment: Thanks I see! :D Working much better now

Answer (score 1):

Put this in the controller:

```
$scope.widget.chosenValue = {};
```

and this in the repeated element:

```
<select ng-model="widget.chosenValue[{{/*$id or $index*/}}]"
```

There are pros and cons of using $id vs $index; using $id is generally safer, but makes keeping track of information slightly more annoying.

Alternatively, you could remove any periods from your ng-model expression, which would cause it to bind that property to the nearest scope, instead of searching for one with the appropriate object. I would not recommend doing this as it makes the model annoying to access with the controller.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to try this method out sometime too

Comment: @LeonGaban I realized that you'll definitely want to use $index, as you have function calls in other html elements, which would have a different $id.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<md-select ng-model="selectedOption"  
ng-change="performAction(selectedOption.chosenValue, selectedOption.tag, selectedOption.item_id)" >
<md-option 
ng-value="item" 
ng-repeat="item in widget.items">{{ item.tag }}</md-option>
</md-select>
```